# XP recovery from boot

Tags: windows-xp, password-recovery

evening all! I bought a second hand cheap laptop from car boot and need to completely reset it but dont have password. Is there a way to do this is guest mode please. XP windows

Much thankz

Comment: Why do you need a password if you're resetting it? Just boot up an install disc and overwrite everything.

Comment: And make sure you run something other than xp; it is long past end of life.

Comment: Some background why to reinstall:
1) No possible virussen or other unpleasant leftovers.
2) Often a better performance than old installls with crud.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to reformat the drive and re-install Windows.

I would suggest, if possible ad the laptop can handle it, to install Windows 7. With Windows XP no longer being supported, there is no reason to re-install it, unless you don't have a choice due to hardware or money reasons.

You will need to get a valid copy of Windows XP or 7 in order to do this. You can grab a DvD copy on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/microsoft-windows-7-8-software/b?ie=UTF8&node=1286119011) if you choose, or you can download a an iso file and create a [Windows 7 USB Boot key](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) (please note that if you use an iso file, you will still need to purchase or obtain a valid product-key to activate the product)

Once you have your DvD or flash drive or Windows XP/7 - place/connect it to your computer and enter your computers boot menu at start (usually F9 or f12 depending on the make). Select either your DvD or Flash Drive and you can follow the prompts on screen in order to reformat the current hard-drive and re-install Windows.